# Binary search vs key based search

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, redis, binary-search

Suppose I have 10000 items, each represented by an id (1, 2, 3 and so on. Also, a key can be any large number upto 10e6) and I have the option of using a key value storage (Redis, to be precise) and a sorted array.

**Key-value:**

```
{
    1: 1,
    2: 2,
    3: 3 //and so on
}
```

**Sorted array:**

```
[1, 2, 3, ...]
```

Now, if I want to search for an item, which would be faster(and why) out of:

1. Accessing the key, example: obj['3'] or,
2. Applying binary search on the sorted array with log(N) complexity?

Or is there any other data structure which would be faster than the above two options.

Comment: Is the domain dense? E.g. will there always be a 4 between the objects with id 3 and 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the domain is **dense** (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and not 1, 4, 6, 18), by far the fastest data structure is a simple array. Then the index of the object is the object id.

You can also use this if your domain is **small**. If all id's are, say, less than 100,000 you can simply make an array with 100,000 elements and have some value indicate a missing element.

If not, then the best option is the key-value data structure. It was optimized for this. It can either be implemented as a hash map or a sorted tree, and you can assume your programming language designers chose the best option for you.

If the choice is up to you (e.g. in C++), a hash map should be the fastest for integer keys.

Comment: I am actually using Python.

Comment: In Python `dict` is a hash map and should be the fastest, unless, again, your domain is small or dense.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific, but I would also need to store this map somewhere(currently, using Redis). Nonetheless thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It all depends how you want to implement the first approach, i.e. a dictionary. If you decide to use a hash table, you can achieve expected `O(1)` time access, however, details also depends on chosen implementation.

Notice, that if your keys are not very large integers, you can use a simple array to access them. Doing this, let's say that your largest key is `K`, you can achieve `O(1)` time access with `O(K)` memory.

Comment: I am using a nosql database, redis to store key value pairs.

Comment: So tag your questions with appropriate tags. Now it looks like you want to know a general, non-technology specific approach.